# Mark faces to use different textures

Tags: texturing, materials, faces

I'm traying to make a material for the leaves of an ivy, and i got 2 different images of leaves.

I would like to keep all the leaves as a one object, with one, material, and somehow mark the faces to use different images and get a better result.
Is it possible, or do I have to select random faces, separate in a new object, and use a different material?

I could use the same material and object id to switch texture, but if possible, as said, i'd prefer keep al the leaves in a single object.

Comment: Look at [this thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?366586-I-can-t-make-the-leaves-of-different-colors-using-IviGen). Also [randomizing leaf color](https://cgcookie.com/archive/tip-randomizing-leaf-color/) probably could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different material settings in 1 shader and mix them.
[image: random mat]
Here you have 2 diffuse shaders using different textures. The mix shader uses as factor a random objet info to choose wich one to use. the color ramp, set on constant, allows to use only 1 one them, not a random mix of the 2 (constant) and the Position at 0.5 allows a 50% mix, but you can have more or less of a material moving the slider left or right.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no direct mechanism to control different textures on a per face basis, however you don't need  to separate into different objects to use different textures or materials.

Either setup two similar materials each using different textures and use different material slots for each (you can use random select to assign materials to randomized faces), or if you really need only one material merge your two textures into a single image file with both leafs and use uv map offset for each face to show whatever leaf you want.

Comment: Yeah, i considered this, but for each leaf i have diffuse, normals, and specular map, so there would be 3 double-sized image files.
For now i made 2 object with different ObjID.
Thanks anyway for the help!